# Generate matrix of combinations with rules, repeated binary choice

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

I am trying to do sampling of variables for a statistical analysis. I have 10 variables, and I want to examine every possible combination of 5 of them. However, I only want those that follow certain rules. I only want those with 1 xor 2, 3 xor 4, 5 xor 6, 7 xor 8 and 9 xor 10. In other words, all combinations given 5 binary choices (32).

Any idea how to do this efficiently?

A simple idea is to find all the 5 out 10 using:

```
library(gtools)
sets = combinations(10,5) # choose 5 out of 10, all possibilities
sets = split(sets, seq.int(nrow(sets))) #so it's loopable
```

And then loop over these keeping only the ones that meet the criteria and thus ending up with the 32 ones desired.

But surely there is a more efficient way than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will construct a matrix whose 32 rows enumerate all the possible combinations satisfying your contraint:

```
m <- as.matrix(expand.grid(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10))

## Inspect a few of the rows to see that this works:
m[c(1,4,9,16,25),]
#      Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
# [1,]    1    3    5    7    9
# [2,]    2    4    5    7    9
# [3,]    1    3    5    8    9
# [4,]    2    4    6    8    9
# [5,]    1    3    5    8   10
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution too, but it's not quite as elegant as Josh O'Brien's above.

```
library(R.utils) #for intToBin()
binaries = intToBin(0:31) #binary numbers 0 to 31
sets = list() #empty list
for (set in binaries) { #loop over each binary number string
  vars = numeric() #empty vector
  for (cif in 1:5) { #loop over each char in the string
    if (substr(set,cif,cif)=="0"){ #if its 0
      vars = c(vars,cif*2-1) #add the first var
    }
    else {
      vars = c(vars,cif*2) #else, add the second var
    }
  }
  sets[[set]] = as.vector(vars) #add result to list
}
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: since you know from the start the "length" of your outcome, it should be a lot faster to _pre-allocate_ your "sets" and "vars". E.g. compare these: `x_full = numeric(1e5); x_empty = numeric(); system.time( for(i in 1:1e5) x_full[i] = i ); system.time( for(i in 1:1e5) x_empty = c(x_empty, i) ); identical(x_full, x_empty)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the idea in your answer, an alternative for the record:

```
n = 5
sets = matrix(1:10, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

#the "on-off" combinations for each position
combs = lapply(0:(2^n - 1), function(x) as.integer(intToBits(x)[seq_len(n)]))

#a way to get the actual values 
matrix(sets[cbind(seq_len(n), unlist(combs) + 1L)], ncol = n, byrow = TRUE)
```